# Remove last 2 numbers from all dictionary values?

Tags: python

Using the below code I am extracting the below dictionary from API:

```
for cv_ver in cv_versions_dic['results']:
rhel_ver = cv_ver['id']
cv_name = cv_ver['name']
if qq_cv(cv_name):
    cv_name = cv_ver['name']
    #print(cv_name)
    cv_ver_dic.update({rhel_ver: cv_name})
print(cv_ver_dic)
```

Output:

```
{327: 'RHEL 6 64-bit 1.0', 355: 'RHEL 5 64-bit 4.0'}
```

There are much more dictionary values, posting just a sample.

I want to remove the last numbers from each value. i.e:

- remove from the first value `1.0` and leave `'RHEL 6 64-bit'`
- remove from the second value `4.0` and leave `'RHEL 5 64-bit'`

Comment: You either have to post more sample data and expected output, or describe your issue more accurately. I have no clue what you're asking.

Comment: The indentation is incorrect, could you format your code correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
cv_name = ' '.join(cv_ver['name'].split(' ')[:-1])
```

should do it...

Explanation:

First we split our string by space character - `cv_ver['name'].split(' ')`
return all elements except the last one - `[:-1]`
and finally, join those list elements back with space character between them - `' '.join()`

As [MSeifert pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309446/remove-last-2-numbers-from-all-dictionary-values#comment75624914_44309610), the alternative can be version with [`rsplit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit):

```
cv_name = cv_ver['name'].rsplit(' ', 1)[0]
```

Comment: Instead of `join` you could also use [`rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) with a maxsplit of 1.

Comment: @MSeifert Sure thing. I tried to use more splitting/joining just to get the idea what can be done with strings... I updated my answer with your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension over the values which are strings like this

```
for cv_ver in cv_versions_dic['results']:
    cv_ver_dic.update({cv_ver['id']:cv_ver['name'][:-3].strip()})
print(cv_ver_dic)
```

now this will do a list comprehension by removing last three characters from the values if you want more values to be removed just increase the no.

so now this yields

```
{327: 'RHEL 6 64-bit', 355: 'RHEL 5 64-bit'}
```